# Regarding Shell variable

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need to call another shell script testarg.sh within my main script.  This script testarg.sh has arguments ARG1 ,ARG2, ARG3. I need to call up the below way:

```
./testarg.sh -ARG1 <value>  -ARG2 <value> -ARG3
```

ARG1 and ARG3 arguments are mandatory ones.  If it's not passed to the main script then I quit. ARG2 is an optional one.  If the ARG2 variable is not set with value or it's not defined then I need not pass it from main script. So I need to call up the below way

```
./testarg.sh -ARG1 <VALUE1> -ARG3
```

If the value exist for the ARG2 Variable then I need to call the below way:

```
./testarg.sh -ARG1 <VALUE1> -ARG2 <VALUE2> -ARG3
```

Do I need to have a if else statement for checking the ARG2 variable is empty or null? Is there any other way to do it?

---

#### Amendment

If ARG2 is set, then the call should be:

```
./testarg.sh -ARG1 -OPT2 $ARG2 -ARG3
```

Comment: Does your script have to be in the shell? It's getting complex enough that personally I would switch to another language, e.g. Python or Perl.

Comment: Your "Amendment" is inconsistent with the rest of the question - which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is in bash, you can write

```
./testarg.sh -ARG1 $ARG1 ${ARG2:+-ARG2 $ARG2} -$ARG3
```

The construct `${param:+word}` evaluates to `word` if `param` is set, or nothing otherwise. So if `$ARG2` has a value, you get `-ARG2 $ARG2`, otherwise nothing.

Comment: Missed out while posting earlier
if ARG2 has a value then i require  
./testarg.sh  -ARG1 -OPT2 <$ARG2>  -ARG3
If ARG2 doesn't have a value then i require 
./testarg.sh  -ARG1 -ARG3

Comment: Yes, Bourne, Korn, POSIX, Bash shells all support the notation.

Comment: And you can do; `./testarg.sh -ARG1 ${ARG2:+-OPT2} $ARG2 -ARG3`.

Comment: @arav: you can edit your question to add the extra detail, rather than replicating a comment around the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    echo ARG1 is null
else
    echo ARG1 = $1
fi
if [ "$2" = "" ]; then
    echo ARG2 is null
else
    echo ARG2 = $2
fi
```

Comment: Missed out while posting earlier if ARG2 has a value then i require ./testarg.sh -ARG1 -OPT2 <$ARG2> -ARG3 If ARG2 doesn't have a value then i require ./testarg.sh -ARG1 -ARG3

Comment: That doesn't help much with the invocation of the sub-script.